# How to remove unwanted gap in bootstrap grid, so that it looks like a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like this which i created with div's. However, if a text is too long, then all the cells from this row will be filled with white background color.

```css
* {
  word-break: break-word;
}       
div {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.main_div {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
p {
  display: inline;
}
#verzeichnis {
  text-align: center;
}
.tabelle {
  background-color: #AAAAAA;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.test {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 tabelle">
    <p id="verzeichnis"> Test 1 </p>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;"> 
      <p id='Datei' class="dateiname_h" style="display:inline"> File <i id="dateiname_h_icon" class='fa fa-toggle-on pull-right'></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #A4AfA4;">  
      <p>Status</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>B</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;"> 
      <p id='Datei' class="dateiname_h" style="display:inline"> short text </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>short text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #A4AfA4;">  
      <p><span style='color:green'><i class='fa fa-check-circle-o'></i></span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>very long text which should break to the next line because word wrap is set to break-word</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;"> 
      <p id='Datei' class="dateiname_h" style="display:inline"> File <i id="dateiname_h_icon" class='fa fa-toggle-on pull-right'></i></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #A4AfA4;">  
      <p>Status</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color: #D8D8D8;">  
      <p>B</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**NOTE**: stackoverflow does not seem to understand bootstrap, even though i included it as external library into my snippet. This is how it should look if you run the snippet:

[image]

My goal is to remove the white gap so it looks like this.[image]

Comment: why don't use table markup for this particular purpose? it will give you much simpler approach to text-alignment and solve your problem as well. So far in your case you will not achieve desired result only with CSS. This is the way Bootstrap cols work. They are just floated DIVs

Comment: Tag ID is unique. You can not assign the same ID to different tags. I mean "Datei" ID

Comment: I use divs because in my oppinion it is much easier to work with them when using jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have used a real table for tabular data. Anyway, you can use CSS `display:table` for a workaround.

**Parent:**

```
.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
```

**Children:**

```
.row .col-sm-3 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}
```

I would suggest applying this CSS to to a specific container to minimize messing with bootstrap's default styling, like `.customTable .row` and `.customTable .row .col-sm-3`

[**jsFiddle example**](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/5yq776om/2/)